# C++ pegtl: how to handle the parsing of unary operators in the pegtl calculator example?

Tags: c++, parsing

How can we extend the https://github.com/taocpp/PEGTL/blob/master/src/example/pegtl/calculator.cpp with unary operators? @ Öö Tiib, user207421: if you want to close this question again - do you really think it is as easy as giving all unary operators a higher precedence than binary operators? The example is using std::function< long( long, long ) to handle binary operators - how can I incorporate unary operators to work with std::function< long( long, long ) ?

I just copied the calculator.cpp to 
https://godbolt.org/z/hHmN9F
so that everybody can play around with it.
On line 345 you can change the input string.
Currently, the output of "0-(3+8)*4" is -44. Would be great if I could avoid the 0 in the input string.

Comment: Just made a new example that also correctly handles arbitrary unary prefix and postfix operators. In the future if you can't find it under this link it might have been promoted to `include/tao/pegtl/contrib`. https://github.com/taocpp/PEGTL/blob/master/src/example/pegtl/expression.cpp